# Splash screen (launch image) vs icon for iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, xcode

I understand that **the splash screen for iPhone apps is the Default.png**. BTW, I am using **XCode4** for development.

**But the problem is that**

**when I try to upload the app using the application loader, application loader tells me that Default.png is too big: "icon dimensions don't meet the size requirement [..] 57x57 pixels".**

If I would change the dimensions the splash screen will lose resolution, thus not looking good. So how can I differentiate between icon and splash screen so the application loader will not give me an error?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing up `Icon.png` and `Default.png`. Both have to have the designated sizes. 
Respectively, **57x57 non-retina**, **114x114 retina** and **320x480 non-retina**, **640x960 retina**.

Make sure that you are **not specifying any non-standard names for your icon files** in your application `plist`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After careful research I would like to contribute. There must be named as follows: Icon.png, Icon@2x.png and Default.png and Default@2x.png at least for iPhone development, for non-retina and retina display respectively.

Comment: Almost. You can also specify your own names in the app plist.

Answer (score 2):

Just make two different files with different dimensions and assign them to appropriate places in the target's summery tab as shown in image below

[image]

**It must be required dimensions as specified in above answer**

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:** *(on 8 Jan 2014)*

the new link for official site is **[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html)**.

**UPDATED:** *(on 29/04/13)*

```
full DEFAULT image set contains:

- 2048 by 1536 (Retina iPad default, landscape)
- 1536 by 2048 (Retina iPad default, portrait)
- 1136 by 640 (Retina iPhone5 default, landscape)
- 1024 by 768 (iPad default, landscape)
- 960 by 640 (Retina iPhone default, landscape)
- 768 by 1024 (iPad default, portrait)
- 640 by 960 (Retina iPhone default, portrait)
- 640 by 1136 (Retina iPhone5 default, portrait)
- 480 by 320 (iPhone default, landscape)
- 320 by 480 (iPhone default, portrait)
```

the ultimate and official Apple documentation is available **[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)** of it.

**ORIGINAL POST:**

here is a **full list of the icons and images for an universal application** to understand how many icons and images would be needed if you want to prepare for your application for everything.

```
full ICON set contains:

- 1024 by 1024 (Retina iTunes artwork)
- 512 by 512 (iTunes artwork)
- 144 by 144 (Retina iPad icon)
- 114 by 114 (Retina iPhone icon)
- 96 by 96 (Retina iPad Spotlight)
- 72 by 72 (iPad icon)
- 58 by 58 (Retina iPhone Spotlight)
- 57 by 57 (iPhone icon)
- 48 by 48 (iPad Spotlight)
- 29 by 29 (iPhone Spotlight)

full DEFAULT image set contains:

- 2048 by 1536 (Retina iPad default, landscape)
- 1536 by 2048 (Retina iPad default, portrait)
- 1024 by 768 (iPad default, landscape)
- 960 by 640 (Retina iPhone default, landscape)
- 768 by 1024 (iPad default, portrait)
- 640 by 960 (Retina iPhone default, portrait)
- 480 by 320 (iPhone default, landscape)
- 320 by 480 (iPhone default, portrait)
```

Comment: Those numbers are incorrect.  Please see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: @Devon, the _incorrect_ is a very strong word here, you should have said it needs to be updated a bit for now.